# Heap showed in ddms

Tags: android

What is the difference between VM heap and native heap shown in ddms? What do they mean and which of them is limited to 16 mb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM heap refers to the heap of **Application**, that is to say specific **Process**

native heap refers to the global heap of **System**

Comment: Thanks. There is an API to get the VM heap without using the ddms?